# MVC- Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

New to MVC, Checked lot of workarounds.. didn't help:

This code is written in model repository, which returns a list that I can return to View(Index)

```
    IList<AccessArticles> publisherList = (from aa in db.AccessArticles
    join u in db.Users on aa.UserId equals u.id
    join a in db.Articles on aa.ArticleId equals a.id
    where u.id == id
    orderby a.title
    select new
    {
       UserName = u.username,
       ArticleTitle = a.title,
       AccessArticlesId = aa.AccessArticlesId,
       ArticleId = aa.ArticleId,
       UserId = aa.UserId
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select
    (x=> new AccessArticles
    {

        AccessArticlesId = x.AccessArticlesId,
        UserId = x.UserId,
        UserName = x.UserName,
        ArticleTitle = x.ArticleTitle

    }).ToList();
```

Error that I get is Specified cast is not valid.

Please suggest a wayout or a better way to get the same effect.

Thanks

### Code reference -

### Interface :

```
List<AccessArticles> SearchByUserId(int UserId);
```

---

### Repository  :

```
public List<AccessArticles> SearchByUserId(int id)
        {
            var setArticles = (from aa in db.AccessArticles
            join u in db.Users on aa.UserId equals u.id
            join a in db.Articles on aa.ArticleId equals a.id
            where u.id == id
            orderby a.title
            select new AccessArticles
            {
              UserName= u.username,
              ArticleTitle = a.title,
              AccessArticlesId= aa.AccessArticlesId,
              ArticleId = aa.ArticleId,
              UserId =  aa.UserId
            }).ToList();

            return setArticles;


        }
```

---

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            int UserId = 0;
            if (id != null)
            {
                UserId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            }
            IAccessArticlesRepository AccessRepository = new AccessArticlesRepository();
            //int count = AccessRepository.SearchByUserId(UserId).Count();
            List_AccessArticles = AccessRepository.SearchByUserId(UserId);
            return View(List_AccessArticles);
        }
```

---

### Model

```
namespace theSiteCMS.Models
{
    public partial class AccessArticles
    {
        public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}


I did some changes taking some reference:



----------
Repository
----------
public IQueryable<AccessArticles> SearchByUserId(int id)
{
var setArticles = (from aa in db.AccessArticles
join u in db.Users on aa.UserId equals u.id
join a in db.Articles on aa.ArticleId equals a.id
where u.id == id
orderby a.title
select new AccessArticles
{
  UserName= u.username,
  ArticleTitle = a.title,
  AccessArticlesId= aa.AccessArticlesId,
  ArticleId = aa.ArticleId,
  UserId =  aa.UserId
});

return setArticles;


}

--------------
Controller
--------------


public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    int UserId = 0;
    if (id != null)
    {
        UserId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    }
    IAccessArticlesRepository AccessRepository = new AccessArticlesRepository();
    var userwisearticles = AccessRepository.SearchByUserId(UserId);
    return View(userwisearticles);
}

Error:

In Index.aspx page:

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

Highlight on 'Model' - Explicit construction of entity type 'theSiteCMS.Models.AccessArticles' in query is not allowed.
```

Comment: You should show us code of classes that you use in this fragment of code

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a new list of AccessArticles from  the EF collections?

Comment: Yes, a list of articles a user has access to in List View.

Comment: Is AccessArticles the EF type describing the table?  I may be off base, but the last time I used EF, AccessArticles would have been the table containing AccessArticle entities.

Comment: Yes,AccessArticles is the mapping table that holds userid and articleid to map user table and article table. The mapping is done in .dbml

Answer (score 0):

This returns a collection of Anonymous types with the properties described below.  If you need to use an existing class, make sure it's not the one your EF is using to represent your entity unless it matches directly.  If that's the case, then you should be able to to replace the `select new` below with `select aa` and have it return a list of the entity models that EF built for you.

```
var publisherList = (from aa in db.AccessArticles
                                 join u in db.Users on aa.UserId equals u.Id
                                 join a in db.Articles on aa.ArticleId equals a.Id
                                 where u.Id == userId
                                 orderby a.Title
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     UserName = u.UserName,
                                     ArticleTitle = a.Title,
                                     AccessArticleId = aa.AccessArticlesId,
                                     UserId = aa.UserId
                                 }).ToList();
```

Edited to select the EF entity directly;

```
var publisherList = (from aa in db.AccessArticles
                                 join u in db.Users on aa.UserId equals u.Id
                                 join a in db.Articles on aa.ArticleId equals a.Id
                                 where u.Id == userId
                                 orderby a.Title
                                 select aa).ToList();
```

That should trigger a compile error because your return type doesn't match.  I'm guessing it has to be `List<AccessArticle>`

Comment: Thanks Barry, but didn't understand exactly what is the issue. If I do, Select aa{} it gives error but works with select new AccessArticles. ** My replies may not be exact, as I have just started to understand MVC. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to see some specific code/table structure to understand more, I share.